# How to pass JSON string as parameter through postman

Tags: json, api, parameters, get, postman

How should I pass a JSON string as parameter through postman?

This is the API, that I want to use:
`/templates/published?page=0&size=25&sort=credentialSchemaIdentifiers,asc&q=Health&filter=&filterDTO={"firstName":"DAN"}`

But for the last parameter `filterDTO` it does not go through and returns a Bad Request error

Answer (score 0):

you better try this

```
... /templates/published?page=0&size=25&sort=credentialSchemaIdentifiers,asc&q=Health&filter=
&filterDTOName=firstName&FilterDtoValue=DAN
```

or you can make a post action

```
[HttpPost("~/templates/published")]
public ActionResult Published ([FromBody] Jobject filterDto, [FromQueryString] int page, int size, ...)
```

put

```
{"firstName":"DAN"}
```

into a Postman body, another parameters into url